# Is it possible to find out when the current syntax of strcpy was added to the C standard?

Tags: c, history

The oldest publicly available `C` standard seems to be the ISO/IEC 9899:1999, published in 1999.
There the `strcpy` function already has its current syntax.

The reason I ask it is that I found a really, really old system where (to my greatest shock) `strcpy` seems to have almost the same syntax as `memcpy`.

In that implementiation strcpy behaves like this:

- `strcpy(char *destination, char *source, int length)` works just like the modern `memcpy`
- `strcpy(char *destination, char *source)` does compile, but it doesn't have any noticeable side-effect, just as if it was called with `length = 0`.
- `strncpy` works exactly just like `strcpy`, it even compiles with just 2 parameters.

So, for someone interested in C-archeology (and having access to very old standards), was there a C standard where `strcpy` was not defined? Which was the first standard where it was defined? Am I dealing with a non-standard conforming compiler (a compiler that doesn't even conform to the oldest C standard)?

I couldn't find any indication which version of C is really supposed to be implemented, the only hint is that it was written before 1997 (as I found the text "Copyright 1997") for a Fujitsu processor.

**Edit:** If [this source](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.11.2.3) is to be trusted, `strcpy` was already defined in its current form already in 1989. So I have to deal with something even older than I first suspected!

Comment: My guess is that both `strcpy` and `memcpy` are from K&R C, before standardization. I have an old C book (packed away in storage since long) from late 1980's or very early 1990's in which both functions was documented (if I remember correctly).

Comment: There is ANSI X3.159-1989 "Programming Language C" dated back in 1989.

Comment: You have to look *much* earlier, according to [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) the `strcpy` function was already in [4.3BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD#4.3BSD) which was released in 1986. Same with [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html).

Comment: "strcpy(char *destination, char *source, int length)" -- No, never. I've been programming in C since Unix V6 and was on the C standards committee. "strcpy(char *destination, char *source) does compile, but it doesn't have any noticeable side-effect" -- not consistent with your first statement. "strncpy works exactly just like strcpy" -- no, never. "it even compiles with just 2 parameters" -- what does that have to do with the price of beans? Sure it will compile if you don't provide a prototype and don't set a warning level.

Comment: "So, for someone interested in C-archeology (and having access to very old standards), was there a C standard where strcpy was not defined?" -- Do you even understand what a C standard is? C compilers existed for nearly two decades before the first C Standard ... and they had strcpy and strncpy with the same semantics as the current ones. memcpy was a relatively late addition, I think in UNIX V7, circa 1979.

Comment: You can extract some information from the standard headers. Look at string.h. Do functions declared there have prototypes? If yes, how strcpy declaration looks there?

Comment: It is highly unlikely thhat any C compiler from any period would behave as you describe. Show a test program you've ran that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: P.S. Before Bell Labs added memcpy to the C library, there was Berkeley's bcopy, defined in strings.h (as opposed to the standard string.h)

Comment: @Jim Balter : what is that you find not consistent? I just described what `strcpy(char *destination, char *source, int length)` and `strcpy(char *destination, char *source)` **do** in this particular compiler, and then stated that `strncpy` does exactly the same. Yes, it seems to be a compiler which doesn't conform to any (modern?) standard, but in what way does it make my description of it "inconsistent"?

Comment: @n.m.: I don't have a standard output as it's a compiler for a microcontroller, not a general-purpose PC. `char s[10]; strcpy(s, "Text", 5);` ends up with `s` containing "Text" correctly, while `strcpy(s, "Text");` ends up with `s` unchanged.

Comment: strcpy cannot both work like memcpy and take only two arguments. It's conceivable that it just happens to be a no-op when given two arguments under certain circumstances when the register or stack location holding the 3rd argument contains 0. Also you say "this particular compiler" -- do you actually physically own a "Fujitsu processor" with this compiler running on it? If not, you can't know how it behaves. If so, why not say more about this processor?

Comment: @JimBalter : Yes I do physically have one, and yes, it really behaves just like I described. It's not a simulation or an emulator.

Comment: "strcpy(s, "Text", 5); ends up with s containing "Text" correctly" -- as it will on most systems, ... "Text" is NUL-terminated, so it's going to work as long as the calling convention allows extra arguments to be ignored. "while strcpy(s, "Text"); ends up with s unchanged" -- so you say but it's highly implausible. Anyway, private microcontroller systems generally don't pay much attention to standards, so asking about standards in regard to them is bogus.

Comment: You wrote "strcpy(char *destination, char *source, int length) works just like the modern memcpy" -- did you call it with a string like "foo\0bar" and have the whole thing copied? Or do you not know how memcpy works?

Comment: how does that even compile if there's no function overloading in C?

Comment: `strcpy(d,s,len)` and `strcpy(d,s)` cannot work differently without special compiler magic. Either one works and the other does not (always) work, or both work identically. Since the magic, if any such exist, looks totally arbitrary and pointless, it is much more likely that your test is simply not accurate. A quick look at a disassembled program would solve the issue. And what about the standard headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first published standard for C was C89 (ANSI X3.159-1989).  It defined `strcpy` as follows:

```
char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Before, that, try looking for the first version of "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, which was the de facto standard from its publication in 1978 to 1989.  I would not be surprised if `strcpy` predates this.

According to http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/, Version 7 UNIX, released in 1979, defined strcpy as

```
char *strcpy(s1, s2)
char *s1, *s2;
```

I wasn't able to find `strcpy` in the documentation for Version 6 UNIX, which was released in 1975, but its "C Manual", written by Dennis Ritchie, contained an example function

```
copy(s1, s2)
char *s1, *s2
{
    while(*s2++ = *s1++);
}
```

Its "C Tutorial", written by Brian Kernighan, instead contained this version:

```
strcopy(s1, s2)
char s1[ ], s2[ ]; {
    int i;
    for( i = 0; (s2[i] = s1[i]) != '\0'; i++ );
}
```

This suggests that the modern version of `strcpy` originated somewhere between the release of V6 UNIX in 1975 and the publication of K&R C in 1978.

Notice that even at this early time, we already see stylistic differences between the two principle authors of C: Kernighan put the opening bracket of functions on the same line as the parameter declaration, while Ritchie preferred to put it on a new line by itself.

Comment: "somewhere between the release of V6 UNIX in 1975 and the publication of K&R C in 1978" -- sure; Bell Labs was busy working on V7 UNIX, released in 1979, and UNIX/PWB V1, released in 1977. The latter was derived from V6 but the systems borrowed things from each other ... I think string.h was in UNIX/PWB V1.

Comment: In K&R we see `s` and `t` used as parameters for `strcpy` with the modern positions. In your samples I see `s1` and `s2` throughout. Also, you seem to have swapped the location of the `src` and `dst`. Is it possible the code samples you provide here are not verbatim copies?  You take time to point out minor white-space style differences so I didn't know if the inversion of parameters was too obvious or unintentionally incorrect.

Comment: ebyrob: The quotes are correct; see http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/doc/c/c6 and http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/doc/ctut/ct3.  I never noticed that the source and destination are opposite from the current convention -- good catch!

Answer (score 3):

`strcpy` is defined in [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) dating to 1978.

Here it is, p88:

```
/* strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version */ 
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
   int i;
   i = 0;
   while ((*s = *t) != '\0') {
      s++;
      t++; 
   }
}
```

Or, as reduced in the text of the greatest programming book ever written:

```
/* strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version 3 */ 
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
       while (*s++ = *t++)
           ;
}
```

Comment: Did K&R v1 really express the prototypes like that?  I thought that it used old-style parameter declarations.

Comment: Is the latter a newer version of K&R?

Comment: I have an original copy of the book at work, so I'll check tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure dawg must be quoting a revised edition.

Comment: I checked a copy of K&R v1 from 1978:  it uses old-style parameter declarations.